# Add, update and read sub-collection in firestore using Angular (@angular/fire)

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to learn firebase. I am making a project like Linkedin using Angular and Firebase.

I am using the @angular/fire package in my project.

So far I have done authentication and adding some basic info of a user. I have `users` collection where each `documentId` have information like `name`, `email` and etc

Now my next goal is to create a work experience section. Since a user can have multiple work experience.

I have to decided to proceed with sub-collection under each user document id instead of creating a separate collection for `work-experience`.

Now I am having a bit trouble how to add sub-collection in my `users` collection.

A user can only add/update one experience at a time. My UI will be something similar to Linkedin. When the 'Add Experience' button is clicked a modal will pop up and there will be a form inside the form with fields such as `jobTitle`, `companyName` and etc. So once the submit is clicked I want to save that data under the `work-experience` sub-collection with a unique documentId.

Currently I am adding my basic info like this

Adding

```
addUser(user: any): Observable<void> {
   const ref = doc(this.firestore, 'users', user.uid);
  return from(setDoc(ref, user));
}
```

Updating

```
 updateUser(user: any): Observable<void> {
    const ref = doc(this.firestore, 'users', user.uid);
    return from(updateDoc(ref, { ...user }));
 }
```

Now I want to add sub-collection called `work-experience` under the `users` collection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72066236/collection-structure-in-firestore) I think you need to add a sub-collection which contains a document with ID `work-experience`.

If my assumption is correct, do as follows to create the `DocumentReference` to this Document:

```
const workExperienceDocRef = doc(this.firestore, `users/${user.uid}/sub-sections/work-experience`);
```

*Note: Make sure to use [back ticks](https://betterprogramming.pub/javascript-how-backticks-work-de269e0fb8ba).*

And then you can set the data of this doc as follows, for example:

```
return from(setDoc(workExperienceDocRef, {experiences: [{years: "2015-2018", company: "comp1"}, {years: "2018-2021", company: "comp2"}]}));
```

---

If you want to create a sub-collection for the user's document, do as follows:

```
const userSubCollection = collection(this.firestore, `users/${user.uid}/sub-collection`);
```

Then you can use the `addDoc()` method, which will automatically generate the document ID.:

```
const docRef = await addDoc(userSubCollection, {
  foo: "bar",
  bar: "foo"
});
```

Comment: Hey there, Thank you. your second solution using the `addDoc` is the one I was looking for. I wanted something like under the `users` collection there will be a sub-collection called `work-experience` which will have unique document id with fields such as `comanyName` and etc.

Comment: If I want to update an existing `work-experience` should I use the `updateDoc` method?

Comment: Yes, `updateDoc()` is for updating a document. But **you need to know it's ID** (you already know it's parent sub-collection). This means that you need to store somewhere the document ID generated by the `addDoc()` method.

Comment: Typos to correct: "But you need to know its ID (you already know its parent sub-collection)"

Comment: Yes for that I need to retrieve the data work-experience sub-collection data when I am signing in my account. Currently I am fetching the users info like this `doc(this.firestore, 'users', user?.uid)`. also this `docData(ref) as Observable<any>`.. How do I access the sub-collection of the `users` collection here.

Comment: "How do I access the sub-collection of the users collection here" As explained in my answer: ``const userSubCollection = collection(this.firestore, `users/${user.uid}/the-name-of-the-subcollection`)``. With this CollectionReference you can [get all the docs in the collection](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#get_all_documents_in_a_collection).

Comment: Hi there I having trying solution you provided for retrieving the sub-collection data. I have tried like this but not getting expected json.  ` const subCollection = getDocs(collection(this.firestore, `users/${user?.uid}/work-experience`));` and then `subCollection.then(res => console.log('RES: ', res))` .. Its showing some sort metaData and etc. Am I making any mistake?

Comment: Please follow the link I've mentioned in my comment. You need tio use the `getDocs`method **which is asynchronous**. `const querySnapshot = await getDocs(collection(...));
querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
  // doc.data() is never undefined for query doc snapshots
  console.log(doc.id, " => ", doc.data());
});`

Comment: @ Renaud Tarnec Thank you very much. I will progress with this for now. If I need any further help I will ask separate question. Thank you very much for all your help. Really appreciate it.

Comment: Hi, could you please take a look at this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72089431/how-to-get-realtime-updates-of-sub-collection-data-of-a-collection